# How to access downloaded jars of Java Web-Start application

Tags: java, classpath, jnlp

Is there any way to refer client side downloaded jars of a JavaWeb Start application in the runtime ?

**JNLP file** is defined as

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp">
...
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="libs/devkit.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.test.proj.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

I would like to start a java process to execute a java command which takes the devkit jar ref in the class path.

**JAVA Program** (Main.java)

```
String devkitRef = ??  // [ I want to get the ref of 'libs/devkit.jar' here]
String cmd = "javac -cp " + devkitRef + " DynamicClass.java";
Runtime terminal = Runtime.getRuntime();
terminal.exec(command, null, path);
```

I was looking for some solutions but couldn't find any proper solution yet.

Please help.

Comment: you could by accessing the cached jars as described here: https://forums.oracle.com/message/5503117#5503117 However please note 1.) it is only working until jdk1.6 (you have to figure out for yourself what changed in jdk1.7
2.) it uses a com.sun.* API which is not official and due to change...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. I'll check this and update you.